# Why does unsetting first element of an array in bash wipe the whole thing?

Tags: arrays, bash, unset

I made a script some time ago to process some daily data in lengths of weeks, months, or even years. One thing I needed to do was drop the first element or I'd end up with a duplicate entry in the result. That script works wonders. Fast forward a few months I needed to make an identical script which differs in calling certain binaries and scripts to process the data. I copied the script and made the relevant changes, leaving the generation of the sequence of dates and dropping of the first element as is. When I run this new script, the entire array of dates gets unset when calling unset for the first element.

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$1" = '' ] || [ "$3" = '' ]; then
    echo -e "Uso:\t$0 <estacion> <inicio> <fin>"
    echo
    echo -e "\tEl argumento 'estacion' es el identificador de una de las estaciones en"
    echo    "maysculas (e.g. RMA1_FDC). Los otros dos--'inicio' y 'fin'--son fechas de la"
    echo    "forma AAAA-[M]M-[D]D, dondeA corresponde a un digito del año, M para el mes, y D"
    echo    "para el dia. Notese que el mes y el dia solo requieren un digito si el valor"
    echo    "para este campo es menor a diez. No es necesario poner '0' adelante del numero"
    echo    "en este caso."
    echo
    echo    "Este programa genera datos en formato CSV (coma separated values) en la salida"
    echo    "estandar. Si desea guardarlos a un archivo, redirija la salida al mismo. Ej."
    echo
    echo    "$0 RMA1_FDC 2018-7-1 2018-12-10 > registro.csv"
    echo

    exit -1
fi

PRECIPITACION_MODELO=2
PRECIPITACION_ESTACION=5
DIA_A=$2
FECHAS=$(seq $(date +%s -d $2) 86400 $(date +%s -d $3))
>&2 echo "Fechas = "${FECHAS[*]}
unset -v FECHAS[0]
>&2 echo "Fechas = "${FECHAS[*]}

echo "fecha,'delta precipitacion',corrida"

for d in ${FECHAS[@]}; do
    DIA_B=$(date +%Y-%-m-%-d -d @$d)
    >&2 echo "$DIA_A -- $DIA_B"
    ./getstationdata  $1 $DIA_A $DIA_B $PRECIPITACION_ESTACION > estacion 2> /dev/null

    ./getwrfdata  $1 $DIA_A $DIA_B $PRECIPITACION_MODELO A > pronostico 2> /dev/null
    echo -n "$DIA_A,"
    ./delta-precipitacion 2> /dev/null | awk 'ORS=NR%3?" ":"\n"' | awk '{print $2 ",A"}'

    ./getwrfdata  $1 $DIA_A $DIA_B $PRECIPITACION_MODELO B > pronostico 2> /dev/null
    echo -n "$DIA_A,"
    ./delta-precipitacion 2> /dev/null | awk 'ORS=NR%3?" ":"\n"' | awk '{print $2 ",B"}'

    ./getwrfdata  $1 $DIA_A $DIA_B $PRECIPITACION_MODELO C > pronostico 2> /dev/null
    echo -n "$DIA_A,"
    ./delta-precipitacion 2> /dev/null | awk 'ORS=NR%3?" ":"\n"' | awk '{print $2 ",C"}'

    ./getwrfdata  $1 $DIA_A $DIA_B $PRECIPITACION_MODELO D > pronostico 2> /dev/null
    echo -n "$DIA_A,"
    ./delta-precipitacion 2> /dev/null | awk 'ORS=NR%3?" ":"\n"' | awk '{print $2 ",D"}'

    DIA_A=$DIA_B;
    DIA_B=$(date +%Y-%-m-%-d -d @$d)
done

rm -f estacion pronostico
```

Note the part where it says

```
>&2 echo "Fechas = "${FECHAS[*]}
unset -v FECHAS[0]
>&2 echo "Fechas = "${FECHAS[*]}
```

I get a series of numbers representing the dates for the first 'echo' but a simple "FECHAS = " and nothing after that for the second one. Ive been stumped over this for a week now. Does anyone know what's wrong with it?

Comment: `FECHAS` isn't an array, you create it with `FECHAS=$(cmd)`, but to get an array you'd need `FECHAS=($(cmd))`. This being said, your shebang line should *not* contain `/bin/sh`, as this wouldn't support arrays in the first place – use `/bin/bash` or `/usr/bin/env bash` instead.

Comment: What is `FECHAS`, it should have been an array but it looks to be used as a variable

Comment: Benjamin W, **D'OH!** Thanks. I just checked the original, that's EXACTLY what's different. Would you please Put it as an answer instead of a comment so I can mark it as the solution? Thanks!

Comment: that other guy's answer has it covered perfectly. Side note: https://www.shellcheck.net wouldn't have told about your exact problem, but others (such as `-1` not being a valid exit status).

Comment: True, but pointing out that the initialization of FECHAS was wrong is the solution to my problem, as well as being the first useful answer is all (and that post wasn't up yet when I got the notification of your reply). The correct way to initialize them is buried in there, and it's hard to extrapolate that I got it wrong without looking at that post and my code a hundred times :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easier way to reproduce your problem:

```
var="foo bar"
echo "The value is: ${var[*]}"
unset -v 'var[0]'
echo "The value is now: ${var[*]}"
```

This outputs:

```
The value is: foo bar
The value is now:
```

This happens because *the variable is not an array*, it's just that bash allows you to treat your regular variable as array with a single value at index 0:

```
var="foo bar"
echo "No index = $var"
echo "[0] = ${var[0]}"
echo "[1] = ${var[1]}"
```

Outputs:

```
No index = foo bar
[0] = foo bar
[1] =
```

If you create an actual array with `var=("foo" "bar")` in the examples above, you get the expected result:

```
No index = foo
[0] = foo
[1] = bar
The value is: foo bar
The value is now: bar
```

Comment: On GNU bash, version 4.3.46, `unset` on a variable throws a right error as expected  - `bash: unset: var: not an array variable`

Comment: Huh. 4.4.19 does not on my system

Comment: All I have to say is: "Oh GNU!".

Comment: Why DOES BASH do that anyway, treat scalars like single element matrices?

Comment: @JamieRamone You access various indices in a scalar, so it's *you* who are treating the scalar as an array. Bash does its best to interpret what you meant by that.

Comment: No, no, no, you misunderstood my question. I'm asking why doesn't BASH abort with an error when it encounters the access of a scalar as if it were an array, why is it considered legal?

Comment: @JamieRamone We can only speculate. Arrays were introduced in Bash 2 in the 90s, inspired by ksh's support from the late 80s. At the time, people didn't consider "fail fast" a great thing, and would often prefer a partial result. You can see the same in contemporary systems like how MSDOS, Visual Basic and PHP will continue on error, how HTML was designed to never give a syntax error even with broken tags, or how TeX will prompt the user for how to fix issues instead of stopping.